# I want to insert "An error occurred object reference not set to an instance of an object while insert and update new record" into database

Tags: asp.net, mysql, c#-4.0

I want to insert and update data into database on button click but when I fill all fields and start debugging and when dubugger is on buyer code this error is occurred  "object reference not set to an instance of an object". Kindly help me.......

```
protected void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["BuyerId"]) > 0)
        {
            oBuyer = new Buyer();
            //Fill object with Text box values
            oBuyer.BuyerId = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["BuyerId"]);
            oBuyer.BuyerCode = txtBuyerCode.Text;
            oBuyer.SunCode = txtSunCode.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerName = txtBuyerName.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress1 = txtBuyerAddress1.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress2 = txtBuyerAddress2.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress3 = txtBuyerAddress3.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress4 = txtBuyerAddress4.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerPostCode = txtBuyerPostcode.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerPhone = txtBuyerPhone.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerFax = txtBuyerFax.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerEmail = txtBuyerMail.Text;
            oBuyer.PfaCode = txtBuyerPFACode.Text;
            oBuyer.Guarantee = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBuyerGuarantee.Text);
            oBuyer.DefaultDestination = ddlBuyerDefaultDestination.SelectedValue;
            oBuyer.HbaLevy = chkHBALeavy.Checked;
            oBuyer.SfiaWhite = chkSFIAPelagic.Checked;
            oBuyer.SfiaPelagic = chkSFIAPelagic.Checked;
            oBuyer.MarketBox = txtBuyerMarketBox.Text;
            oBuyer.Comments = txtComments.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerRegistrationNo = txtBuyerRigistrationNo.Text;

        }
        else
        {
            //Fill object with Text box values
            oBuyer.BuyerCode = txtBuyerCode.Text;
            oBuyer.SunCode = txtSunCode.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerName = txtBuyerName.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress1 = txtBuyerAddress1.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress2 = txtBuyerAddress2.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress3 = txtBuyerAddress3.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerAddress4 = txtBuyerAddress4.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerPostCode = txtBuyerPostcode.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerPhone = txtBuyerPhone.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerFax = txtBuyerFax.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerEmail = txtBuyerMail.Text;
            oBuyer.PfaCode = txtBuyerPFACode.Text;
            oBuyer.Guarantee = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBuyerGuarantee.Text);
            oBuyer.DefaultDestination = ddlBuyerDefaultDestination.SelectedValue;
            oBuyer.HbaLevy = chkHBALeavy.Checked;
            oBuyer.SfiaWhite = chkSFIAPelagic.Checked;
            oBuyer.SfiaPelagic = chkSFIAPelagic.Checked;
            oBuyer.MarketBox = txtBuyerMarketBox.Text;
            oBuyer.Comments = txtComments.Text;
            oBuyer.BuyerRegistrationNo = txtBuyerRigistrationNo.Text;
        }

        //enter into nSYScatch6 service
        bool saveBuyer = nSYSCatch6ServiceInitiator.SaveBuyer(oBuyer);
        if (saveBuyer)
        {
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `oBuyer = new Buyer();` in the `else` branch.